# Javascript split string at . but not . after quotes

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically if i have `"this.that"` i want that to become `['this', 'that']` but `"this.('.that')"` or `'this.(".that")'` to become `['this', '(".that")']` is that possible with string.split() or not?

Comment: So you want this.that to be this, that, but you also want this.('.that') to be this, ('.that'), and you want to do this with that? :-)

Comment: yes, basically i am trying to write a switch statement to turn jquery into js so if you wrote $('p').hide() that would hide all the p tags but if you wrote $('.p').hide() that would hide all of the .p classes my problem is that its splitting $('.p').hide() into $(', p'), hide() when i need $('.p'), hide()

Comment: Any clue at all, i have the code wrote for the switch to convert the strings but not the split function

Comment: Please post more examples of what the inputs can be. Right now `input.split(/(?<!['"])\./)` would work for the ones you posted but I doubt this is what you need.

Comment: yeah jquery selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> basically i am trying to write a switch statement to turn jquery into js so if you wrote $('p').hide() that would hide all the p tags but if you wrote $('.p').hide() that would hide all of the .p classes

It seems you don't want to use jQuery, and you're trying to write a parser that converts jQuery code into corresponding DOM APIs. This can be a recipe for disaster. It makes more sense to create a simple constructor function that somehow works like jQuery. Something like:

```
function $(selector) {
    if (!(this instanceof $)) {
        return new $(selector);
    }

    this.length = 0;

    if (typeof selector === 'undefined') {
        return this;
    }

    var q = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0, l = q.length; i < l; i++) {
        this[i] = q[i];
    }
    this.length = q.length;
    return this;
}

$.prototype.each = function(cb) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        cb.apply(this[i], [i, this[i]]);
    }
    return this;
}

$.prototype.hide = function() {
    return this.each(function(i, el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

The `$` function accepts all the selectors that [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) accepts.